# Plotly Dash with Postgresql into a docker container

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, plotly-dash

My dash app fetches the data from a postgresql instance on localhost.

Is there any solution to create a micro service with docker-compose that could replicate the service on localhost or i have to create them and manually configure the containers?

My issue now is that for my app to be run needs to have access to the db.

Any reference or ideas are much appreciated!

My docker-compose file:

```
 version : '3'

services:

    pgsql:
        image: postgres
        container_name: dash_pgsql
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=XXX
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        volumes:
            - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    dash:
        build:
            context: . 
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.dash
        container_name: dash_app
        command: python app.py 
        volumes:
            - .:/app 
        ports:
            - "80:8050"
        depends_on:
            - pgsql
```

Comment: So you want to run the app locally, i.e from an IDE, but you need the Postgres DB for the app to run? Is that correctly understood?

Comment: @emher Yes exactly

Answer (score 0):

You want to have more of the same compose service (like more instances of dash, for example)? If you only want more of the same service, you could use docker swarm [replicas](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#configs) inside you compose config for that specific service. There is also this [scale](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/scale/) option, but I never used it.

If you want to scale your service based in some metric (cpu/ram usage etc), you'll need an docker container management like kubernetes or docker swarm.